# Insert multiple items in Laravel Collection inside a php loop

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I am trying to insert multiple items into a laravel collection inside a php loop but only one is getting inserted (the last one), please help to insert all the values.

This array `$some_array = array();` has values like 1,2,3,4

The loop is like

```
foreach ($some_array as $key => $value) {

                $final_lists = collect([
                    (object) [
                        'customer_id' => $value,
                    ],
                ]);
            }
```

Output required

```
"final_lists": [
        {
            "customer_id": 4,
             "name": "Name 1",
        },
        {
            "customer_id": 2,
            "name": "Name 2",
        },
]
```

Comment: you can use collect() (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#creating-collections). Just use `collect(array)`. can you please share the needed output?

Comment: $final_lists->push('customer_id',$value); seems to be adding but the result is not a collection it is an associative array

Comment: why need foreach just put $some_data into collect function `$final_list = collect($some_array);`

Comment: In the above code of yours. collect() helper/method seems to be creating a new empty collection every time in each loop which is why you can only see the last element in your collection. create a collection before the loop and keep inserting values in collection inside loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use collection class at the top of the page.as,

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
```

```
$collection = new Collection;

foreach([1,2,3,4] as $item) {
    $collection->push((object)[
        'customer_id' => $item,
        'name' => 'demostring'.$item
    ]);
}

dd($collection->all());
```

use this snippet. Let me know the results.

Answer (score 0):

If you require a list of multiple collections, you can append a new collection to an array like:

```
$a = [1,2,3,4,5]; // Your Array
$requiredList = [];
foreach($a as $key => $value){
    $requiredList[] = (object)[
        'customer_id' => $value,
        'name' => 'Customer Name: ' . $value
    ];
}
dd($requiredList);
```

It will provide the desired list like:

```
^ array:5 [▼
  0 => {#3971 ▼
    +"customer_id": 1
    +"name": "Name1"
  }
  1 => {#3207 ▼
    +"customer_id": 2
    +"name": "Name2"
  }
  2 => {#3977 ▼
    +"customer_id": 3
    +"name": "Name3"
  }
  3 => {#3961 ▼
    +"customer_id": 4
    +"name": "Name4"
  }
  4 => {#3956 ▼
    +"customer_id": 5
    +"name": "Name5"
  }
]
```